# Call to a member function phone() on null

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I am trying to store phone record using one to one relationship.

```php
public function store(Request $request) {

    $user= auth()->user(); 

    $phone= new Phone();

    $phone->cellno= request('cellno');

    $user->phone()->save($phone); 
    return redirect('/phones');
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is there any code involved that you want to share? And what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase i have 2 tables . User which is created by auth and the second is Phone . i want to save cellno according to user_id .

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question by editing it

Comment: For the given error message, I would assume that `$user` is `null` - so what have you tried to debug this?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes $user is null , but in my users table , i have two records but still error occur . then  how is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way to retrieve the authenticated user is indicated in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user).

The line:

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

Should be:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

And don't forget to use the class Auth:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Explanation:

The `auth()` or `user()` methods are not available in your current context, so that's why `$user` will be `null` if none of them were found.

**Edit:**

The authentication will also return null if none user is authenticated, you must follow the documentation provided below for implementing it. Then, you can [secure your Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#protecting-routes).

Basically you have two options:

a) Add the middleware in the route specification:

```
Route::resource('phones' , 'PhoneController')->middleware('auth');
```

b) Add the middleware into the construct of the class (recommended for controllers)

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

After that, if there is not authenticated user the access will be restricted.

Comment: @harisali Then that means there is not authenticated user. Can you update your question with the `/phone` route configuration?

Comment: i am using the Route::resource('phones' , 'PhoneController');

Comment: @harisali I've updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: i try your solution its work and i get the authenticated user Thanks (y)

Comment: @harisali Good to know, please consider selecting the answer as accepted for helping further people.